# Why is position: fixed; not working in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a demo of HTML and CSS. My page doesn't have much content, but it has a sidebar and drawer. I am facing one issue in the sidebar.

I applied the following CSS to my sidebar:

```css
.sidebar {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

After that, I apply the `display: flex;` property to the parent `div` element Now my sidebar is displayed at the right.

My question is this: Why do I need `display: flex;` to make my sidebar display properly?

[Here's a link to my code](https://jsbin.com/cudewiyaja/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: You need to add top : 0 to the sidebar

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `top: 0;` to your `.sidebar` class, then you can remove the `display: flex;`.